# How can I know which button was clicked in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I am making a simple game in Flash CS6.

There are 3 layers:

1. Action
2. Layer 1
3. Layer 2

In layer 1 there are 3 buttons:

- button 1, button 2 and button 3.

Each button sends you to frame 5 on layer 2.  For example, there is another button, FORWARD button.

How can I know on frame 5 which button was clicked? And how can I make it go to different frames by clicking in the FORWARD button depending if came from button 1, 2, or 3.

Comment: Please update your question to show the code you're currently using for the clicks.

Answer (score 0):

For whichever `function` you use your `click` `event` for going to different frame, just add the condition in the function definition:

```
if (event.target == btn_1) //btn_1 is the instance name of button 1
  { //add whatever you want to do with it
  } 
else if (event.target == btn_2) // btn_2 is the instance name of button 2
  {
  }
```

add as many conditions as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Problem SOLVED.

Add:

var bt:int=0;

In each button function ad bt=1, bt=2 and bt=3.

Then in the other button function add:

If bt=1 gotoAndStop(5), if bt=2 gotoAndStop(6), if bt=3 gotoAndStop(7)

Thanks anyway :)